# SQL Sysdate Range

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to use the below query to find work orders that have been closed between a 1 and 4 day range from current date and am not having much luck..

```
SELECT B.ITEMNO,
       B.DESCRIP2
FROM   HIST_ILLUM_RT A,
       HIST_ILLUM_PART B
WHERE  A.TEAR_DOWN_TIME <= SYSDATE -1  AND A.TEAR_DOWN_TIME >= SYSDATE -4
```

The query seems to be pulling all work orders closed. The TEAR_DOWN_TIME field is formatted in MM/DD/YYYY HH/MM/SS

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you join the tables `HIST_ILLUM_RT` and `HIST_ILLUM_PART`? Are you cross joining them?

Comment: Why are you storing DATE values in a `VARCHAR` column. That is a really bad idea

Comment: @Junjie that was my issue.. Figured it out down the road.

Answer (score 1):

Ranges normally have a form "greater than x and less than y"

You've used "less than" twice

Did you mean

```
A.TEAR_DOWN_TIME >= SYSDATE -4
```

Other points of note:

- Prefer ANSI join syntax (inner/left/right/full) over the 80s style table,table where
- Date/time data in a column with a proper datetime or similar type doesn't have a format, strings that look like times have a format. Th database might have a default format that is used when convertIng date/time type data to a string but it's unrelated to how data is stored. Always store your time data as a datetime kind, as **storing it as string can lead to poor performance and unpredictable comparison**

Comment: My apologizes, that was an error on entry of the query. I am using >= -4 and it is still pulling in all work orders closed.

Comment: Edit your question to include the ouput from DESCRIBE HIST_ILLUM_RT and DESCRIBE HIST_ILLUM_PART

Comment: (The request to describe is to check how the dates are stored)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your columns to dates:

```
WHERE TO_DATE(A.TEAR_DOWN_TIME, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24/MI/SS') <= SYSDATE - 1  AND
      TO_DATE(A.TEAR_DOWN_TIME, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24/MI/SS') >= SYSDATE - 4
```

Your logic is doing string comparisons.  Moral?  Store data using the correct data type.

Comment: Specifically (if this is true) what he really needs to do is convert the columns in his table to be datetimes, and then go back to using the original query :)

Comment: I used the above WHERE statement and am now receiving an error stating : a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected.

This column is stored as a date type in the database.

Comment: @JeffGuttry . . . If the column is stored as a date, then it doesn't have a format -- and your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

By using ANSI join (as noted by Caius Jard), and assuming that the primary keys of your tables are both `ID`, try the following code:

```
SELECT B.ITEMNO, B.DESCRIP2
FROM HIST_ILLUM_RT A
  JOIN HIST_ILLUM_PART B ON A.ID=B.ID
WHERE A.TEAR_DOWN_TIME <= SYSDATE-1 AND A.TEAR_DOWN_TIME >= SYSDATE-4;
```

Just a note: I would personally rewrite the *where* clause so that the `TEAR_DOWN_TIME` is in between your border dates, for easy reading, like so:

```
WHERE SYSDATE-4 <= A.TEAR_DOWN_TIME and A.TEAR_DOWN_TIME <= SYSDATE-1
```